# Open source backup software for Windows

Tags: windows, backup

I am looking for an open source program (preferably available on GitHub) for Windows, with graphical interface. I only need to backup files and folders by copying them to a local backup folder, on one of the drives installed on the system. I don't need FTP, SSH, cloud server support, none of that. Just simply schedule backups and copy files and folders when asked to.

I am using Windows 10 64 bit